# what is the best open source framework for programmatically producing .mov or .flv video files?

Tags: animation, open-source, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I would like to programmatically produce a simple animation video.  Don't think "Toy Story" level of animation, think simple stick figures moving around the screen and other very simple lines and dots in black and white only.  The point of the video is to explain a complicated scientific concept with a 5 minute video vs. pages and pages of text trying to describe images with words.

What is the best open source framework to make a .mov or .flv file that I can then upload to youtube or vimeo.  I could use ImageMagick to write out jpeg after jpeg, and then ffmpeg to turn those jpegs into a .mov file.  But is there a better framework out there for simple animation like this?  I feel like the ImageMagick to ffmpeg route is going to involve a lot of me writing code from scratch to make a stick figure walk across the screen.

Comment: Mentioning your operating system could help others answer your question, e.g., Linux, MacOS, Windows.

Comment: i'm flexible.  if there is a great framework that only works on one OS I'll use that OS.

Comment: Have you considered CSS? There are some great CSS animation demos out there. Here's a stick-figure animation: http://jeffri.net/2010/06/moving-stick-figure-with-css-3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally people have used Adobe/Macromedia Flash for such problems. These days javascript and HTML5 canvas seem promising and popular.

There are plenty of Open Source Flash like IDEs if you want to go with that.
http://osflash.org/projects

If you want to have some fun I'd actually recommend Processing and going into the javascript direction.

http://processingjs.org/

https://github.com/fjenett/processing-video-js

or many other JS alternatives...

http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos

https://github.com/dkln/canvas_library/